# Select CFA variables

Tags: r

I'm doing `cfa` on R and I've what I'm sure are two dumb question: 
1. One of my models doesn't use all the variables of my original data (they originally are `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9` and my model uses only `x1, x2, x3, x5, x8 and x9`), so when i use `cfa` only with my desired variables R gives me an error, because of the missing one. Right now I've tried to solve this problem by making a new `.csv file` with only the variables that I need. But I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to do so. 
2. Second question once I got my model fit is there a way to put the output in a nice table instead of the classic ## that R gives? 
I'd like to do this also for my other analysis like KMO and so on,
thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem you can look at the `classes` of your data, because it often is the main reason why functions won't work on the whole `dataframe`. Can you give more input on how your data looks (can you edit your question by giving input via the `dput` function on your `df`).

By "output" of the model, do yo mean saving the `data` to your computer or do you mean you want to put it into another `dataformat` or `table`. Please clarify your your exact question.
While editing you can post your exact error message as well.